# Change colors in Gnuplot like the ones from the gallery

Tags: colors, gnuplot, color-scheme

I used Google and searched on stackexchange, stackoverflow.
How can I reproduce the plots from
http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/simple.html
with the colors from there?

Using the given script

```
# set terminal pngcairo  transparent enhanced font "arial,10" fontscale 1.0 size 500, 350 
# set output 'simple.1.png'
set key inside left top vertical Right noreverse enhanced autotitles box linetype -1 linewidth 1.000
set samples 50, 50
plot [-10:10] sin(x),atan(x),cos(atan(x))
```

on gnuplot (windows 7) always produce a plot with the colors green, red, blue:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/23/unbenanntfkh.png/

I know that I can specify the colors for every single function. Where can I change (global) the colors in my plots?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `set linetype` to define the default linetypes.

```
set linetype 1 lc rgb "blue"
set linetype 2 lc rgb "#EE5500"
```

" The `set linetype` command allows you to redefine the basic linetypes used
 for plots.  The command options are identical to those for "set style line".
 Unlike line styles, redefinitions by `set linetype` are persistent;  they
 are not affected by `reset`."

To load your settings on every gnuplot session automatically, just put these commands in the gnuplot config file, which is `.gnuplot`on linux/unix or `GNUPLOT.INI`on windows:

Comment: thank. looking for gnuplot.ini leads me to "colors_default.gp" which cannot be loaded automatically in the portable version. Unfortunately I always have to execute the content in wgnuplot by hand.